# How can I provide dividers and control item alignment in a Grid?

Tags: grid-layouts, alignment

I make a `Grid` with multiple Rows and Columns.

I want to apply different types of Dividers and Alignment to that `Grid`.

[image]

If you can observe above picture,

1.First row `Alignment` is `Left`,and remaining all the rows `Alignment` is `center`.

2.in the second row only `Dividers` are appeared

I want like this,for this purpose I wrote a simple code but it was nor working

```
 Grid[{{Style["Life Alerts", Bold, 20], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}, 
       {Style["Alert", Bold, 15], Style["<>", Bold, 15], 
        Style["%Life", Bold, 15], 
        Style["OnDay", Bold, 15]
       },
       {Style["L1", Bold, 15], 
        Style["<", Bold, 15], Style["90", Bold, 15], 
        Style["0.35", Bold, 15]
       },
       {Style["L2", Bold, 15], 
        Style[">", Bold, 15], Style["90", Bold, 15], 
        Style["0.35", Bold, 15]
       },
       {Style["L3", Bold, 15], 
        Style[">", Bold, 15], 
        Style["90", Bold, 15], 
        Style["0.35", Bold, 15]
       }
      },
     Alignment -> {{Left}, Center}, Background -> {None, {Yellow}}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[4], Black], Spacings -> {1, 1}, 
   Dividers -> {{}, {True, True, True}}]
```

Already I seen documentation still I didn't get it

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

another way

```
  Grid[{
  {Item["life alerts",Frame->True, Background -> Green,Alignment -> Left], SpanFromLeft},
  {Item["Alert", Frame -> True], Item["% Life",Frame->True],Item["On day",Frame-> True]},
  {"L1", 98, .52},
  {"L2", 97, .77},
  {"L3", 95, 1.27}
  }, Alignment -> {Center}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This reference here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GridsRowsAndColumns.html

has good table to keep handy. Here is a copy of it.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that Dividers only work on the whole grid at once. Not on specific rows/columns. So to do the above in another way, need to use Frame, not Dividers. Either way, I always had hard time with this, so you are not alone. I found the `Item` trick by accident one day when I was trying something, and I use it when needed for special lines like in this case. `Item` is an amazing function. I use it for another very important thing inside Manipulate.

You'll find Another useful function on this page to make it easy to add divider between rows written by Heike. I used it few times myself. It makes it very easy to add a line between rows.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875970/any-trick-to-add-a-divider-inside-a-grid-between-rows-at-the-point-it-is-needed

Comment: Dividers definitely do work on specific rows and columns. Descriptions of this are given in the docs.

Comment: I was commenting about how dividers can be used. I never said any tables were wrong.

Comment: ok now we are on the same page. The table is clearly wrong because divider usage for rows and columns appears in the documentation-- in fact even in the very same tutorial. And I also notice that is says that `Row` does not take any options which is also incorrect.

Comment: They may mean "elements within a row or column" ...which would be correct. But then again there is the statement about Row not having options which is unambiguous (and wrong) so who knows what the intentions of the author were.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to style a grid it is better IMO to do this with `Grid` options and keep content and styling separate: `Grid[content, options(styling)]`. Wrapping data elements in `Item` is (manually) inefficient and soon becomes impractical as the size of the data grows. It is also inefficient/impractical to do this if you are generating data dynamically in some way. Therefore it is best to leave data as it is and use it directly as the first argument to `Grid` and then adjust your styling with the `Grid` options.

If you want a grid like in the image in your question then try these `Grid` options -- using your code with the second column removed (not sure why the second column is there).

```
Grid[{{Style["Life Alerts", Bold, 20], SpanFromLeft, 
   SpanFromLeft}, {Style["Alert", Bold, 15], Style["%Life", Bold, 15],
    Style["OnDay", Bold, 15]}, {Style["L1", Bold, 15], 
   Style["90", Bold, 15], 
   Style["0.35", Bold, 15]}, {Style["L2", Bold, 15], 
   Style["90", Bold, 15], 
   Style["0.35", Bold, 15]}, {Style["L3", Bold, 15], 
   Style["90", Bold, 15], Style["0.35", Bold, 15]}},

 (* options *) 
 Alignment -> {{Center, 1 -> Left}, Center}, 
 Background -> {None, {Green}}, 
 Frame -> {Automatic, Automatic, {{2, 1} -> Blue, {2, 3} -> True}}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[4], Black], 
 Dividers -> {{1 -> True, -1 -> True}, {1 -> True, 2 -> Red, 
    3 -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Orange], -1 -> True}},
Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

Note that I made a few departures with the styling so you could see how to make specific one off changes to divider styling. Also rather than wrap each element in an identical `Style` it would be better to set an `ItemStyle` (or `BaseStyle`, you could also add a `BaseStyle` choosing font and font size etc.):

```
Grid[{{"Life Alerts", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}, {"Alert", "%Life", 
   "OnDay"},
  {"L1", 98, .52}, {"L2", 97, .77}, {"L3", 95, 1.27},
  {"L4", 85, 3.21}, {"L5", 60, 6.23}},(*options*)
 Alignment -> {Center, Center, {{1, 1} -> Left}},
 Background -> {None, {Lighter[Green, 0.6]}}, 
 Frame -> {Automatic, Automatic, {{2, 1} -> True, {2, 3} -> True}}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[4], Black], 
 Dividers -> {{1 -> True, -1 -> True}, {1 -> True, 2 -> True, 
    3 -> True, -1 -> True}},
 ItemStyle -> {Automatic, {Automatic, 1 -> Bold}},
 ItemSize -> 6,
 Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

The advantage of this approach is that for large grids it is easier to maintain than wrapping elements in `Item` -- grid content is separate from the styling (which is controlled by the grid options).

[image]

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi grid styling is something I do regularly but initially it was trial an error.